# How to count number of cells over multiple worksheets whose values are in between a given range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, array

I have an Excel workbook with numerous worksheets containing data like:

```
    'DATA_1'                        'DATA_2'                        'DATA_3'        
    A       B                       A       B                       A       B       
1   value1     1.6              1   value1     0.8              1   value1     2.0  
2   value2     2.5              2   value2     2.2              2   value2     0.5  
3   value3     3.4              3   value3     3.1              3   value3     3.2
```

There is another worksheet called `SUMMARY`, in front of all others, which looks like this:

```
    'SUMMARY'                       
    A       B       C       D       
5           min     max     count   
6   value1     1.0     1.8          
7   value2     1.5     2.5          
8   value3     2.0     3.0
```

The rows `1` to `4` which are not shown are empty and hidden.

As you might already have guessed, I am now trying to fill the column `count` (`D`) properly. It should contain the count of all `value?` values throughout the `DATA_?` sheets that are in the respective range from `min` to `max` limits (a value equaling either of the limits is considered in range). So what I am expecting for the given sample data is:

```
    D       
5   count   
6        1  
7        2  
8        0
```

---

What I have so far is a user-defined function to retrieve an array of worksheet names, which works fine:

```
Function SHEET_NAMES() As Variant
    ' returns names of all sheets as an array
    Dim index As Long, retArray() As String
    Application.Volatile True

    ReDim retArray(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    For index = 1& To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        retArray(index) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(index).Name
    Next index
    SHEET_NAMES = retArray
End Function
```

Moreover, I can successfully access the `value1` data (representatively) in all the worksheets with `{=N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))}`.

I am able to check the `value1` values against their `min` limits with `{=N(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))>=B6)}`. When this array function is spanned over 4 cells, it results in:

```
 0       1       0       1
```

I am able to check the `value1` values against their `max` limits with `{=N(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))<=C6)}`. When this array function is spanned over 4 cells, it results in:

```
 1       1       1       0
```

Finally, I am also able to test the cells for numeric values with `{=N(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES()))))}`. When this array function is spanned over 4 cells, it results in:

```
 0       1       1       1
```

The `0` comes from the `SUMMARY` worksheet whose cell `B1` is empty as already mentioned.

My idea is now to use function `SUMPRODUCT` finally and so to get the individual counts: `{=SUMPRODUCT(N(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))>=B6);N(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))<=C6);N(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1);COLUMN(B1);;;SHEET_NAMES())))))}`.
However, although I expect `1 = (0 * 1 * 0) + (1 * 1 * 1) + (0 * 1 * 1) + (1 * 0 * 1)`, this always results in `0` strangely. So could you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

(I would prefer a solution without using `COUNTIF`, `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIF`, `SUMIFS`, and other similar functions that need the condition to be given as a string, if possible.)

Comment: Are your value#'s always in the same position on every sheet? How many sheets is "numerous"?

Comment: Yes, the `value?` sheets all look exactly the same, the values are all at the same positions, only the values themselves are different; the number of sheets varies from 1 up to ~ 30...

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe, sorry but I can't quite follow... are you referring to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1229700) of mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your UDF to look like this:

```
Function SHEET_NAMES() As Variant
    ' returns names of all sheets as an array
    Dim index As Long, retArray() As String, i As Long
    index = 1
    i = 1
    Application.Volatile True

    ReDim retArray(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1)
    Do While index <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(index).Name <> "SUMMARY" Then
            retArray(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(index).Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
        index = index + 1
    Loop
    SHEET_NAMES = retArray
End Function
```

The only really significant change is that I made it ignore the SUMMARY sheet.

And then use this array formula, adapted from [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/02/19/3d-array-formulas/) (confirm with ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=SUM(IF(N(INDIRECT(SHEET_NAMES()&"!B"&ROW()-5))>=B6,IF(N(INDIRECT(SHEET_NAMES()&"!B"&ROW()-5))<=C6,1,0),0))
```

Note that for this to work, your data on the SUMMARY sheet has to start on row 6 (like your sample). If it doesn't, you'll have to tweak the `ROW()-5` bit so that it equals 1 on your first row. It has to work this way because that's what increments the row when you autofill the formula down.

Edit: Addressing your comments, use this formula. It can be used with your original UDF and utilizes `ADDRESS()` to create the references.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1),,,SHEET_NAMES())))>=B6,IF(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(B1),COLUMN(B1),,,SHEET_NAMES())))<=C6,1,0),0),0))
```

Comment: When I nest another `IF` with the `ISNUMBER` query, can I avoid modifying the `SHEET_NAMES` function? unfortunately, hard-coded exclusion of (a) certain sheet(s) is not a good option for me...

Comment: ...moreover, is it necessary to remove the `ADDRESS` function? as far as I saw, that part worked well...

Comment: @aschipfl see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, @Kyle, I'll test it soon... do you have an idea why my `SUMPRODUCT` approach is failing?

Comment: @aschipfl It has something to do with your third argument, the `N(ISNUMBER(...` part, which I think you are using to filter out your SUMMARY sheet. When I used my UDF and took that part out it worked.

Comment: unfortunately the new formula you added in your [edit](http://superuser.com/revisions/989261/2) returns a too high count, it regards the `SUMMARY` sheet; it's the same wrong result I get with my original formula with the whole `N(ISNUMBER(...))` part removed; to see the error you need to change the limit ranges so that they cross `0`; the empty cell in `SUMMARY` is treated as `0`; I can't figure out a formula that successfully filters out blank cells...

Comment: @aschipfl This problem is solved if you just exclude the summary sheet from your UDF. If you don't want to hard-code it you could provide the name of the sheet to exclude as an argument, or use `Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name` to get the name of the sheet from which the function was called.

Comment: Yes, @Kyle, the problem is solved -- thank you! though I still don't get why the third component of my original formula (`ISNUMBER()`) caused the whole formula to fail, so I posted another [question](http://superuser.com/q/992352/489381) concerning that issue, maybe you are interested...