# How to put a TAB character in a file/dir. name?

Tags: windows, ntfs

On Windows, besides the reserved characters (`"`, `:`, `/`, `\`, `?`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `|`), control characters (such with an ASCII less than `0x20` and also the `0x7F` character) are not allowed in file and directory names (usually).

There should be a way though to get the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character (horizontal tabulator, ASCII `0x09`) in a file or directory name (although it might not be possible as the first and/or last character).

So how can I get the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character in a file and directory name on an NTFS volume with native Windows tools? I am quite sure there is a way in Windows, although I do not know what about NTFS.

Comment: *"There should be a way though to get the TAB character ... in a file or directory name"* -- Says who?  *"I am quite sure there is a way in Windows,"* -- Your conjecture is worthless; prove it.

Comment: Years ago I found a short instruction on the web how to accomplish that (I think it was on Windows XP), but I have no clue what it was, unfortunately; as soon as I find it again, I am able to prove my conjecture, and the question is solved. Anyway, is "not possible" a reason for down-voting?

Comment: I think your downvotes are because you are saying something is both not-permitted, and should be possible.  You are welcome to [edit] and clarify. But really, the clarification will read "I understand this is not permitted, but I remember something were it was possible for an old OS so is it possible now?", to which you'll still get "no".

Comment: @dbenham, on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6895&p=44813#p44813) you mention that you are able to get the TAB character in a file name; would you mind to share your knowledge here? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your question answers itself.  From MSDN:

> Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1
>   through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>   are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>   Streams.

There is no reason to expect that 0x09 should be permitted in a file name when it is explicitly not permitted, as you point out in your first paragraph.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I know the article you linked, but there are so many hidden and undocumented features, particularly when it comes to `cmd` (for instance, wild-cards `<` and `>`, redirection syntax `> file/dev. command`, just to name some), so I do not consider Microsoft documentation as the final word...